# Plane wave solution with mirror boundary at $z = 0$

Tags: electromagnetism, boundary-conditions

I'm trying to understand what's written in a journal paper (https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/2040-8986/ab7b01/meta) pp.19 that I'm studying.
In summary, there's a bulk metal that acts as a perfect mirror at $z\leq0$. In $x$- and $y$-direction, the metal is infinite. Anywhere above $z = 0$ is air/vacuum. The paper gave me two electric polarizations of an arbitrary wavevector ($\vec{k}$) that is allowed in vacuum.

[image]

Then the paper says

> 'A good mirror is typically a good conductor. In the presence of an electric field the charges within the conductor move, canceling the in-plane electric field at the surface. A mirror can therefore be mimicked using the boundary condition that the in-plane electric field is zero.'.

--> Actually, I have one question here: Shouldn't a boundary condition of electric fieldon perfect electric conductor 'tangential component of $E = 0$'? I'm confused why it's the 'in-plane' electric field $= 0$.

Then the paper says:

> 'We take the surface of the mirror to be at $z = 0$, and sum together pairs of the allowed modes in free space (66)
>
> [image]
>
> such that the in-plane electric field is zero in this plane.
>
> For the two types of polarization defined in (65) we have either (for polarization e2),
>
> [image]

Now, I can't figure out how the sum of the above two opposite waves can result in in-plane electric field to be zero.

I would really appreciate if anyone with good electromagnetic/math/physics background help me understand this a little more.

Comment: Which paper is that? What are $n_x,n_y,n_z?$ "in-plane" = "tangential component".

Comment: I added the link to the paper on my question. Oh, okay. That in-plane electric field = tangential E = 0 is the right boundary condition. Then it looks to me that the summation of the two plane waves with opposite n_x makes the Ez component to be zero. Is that correct?